# Render function inside component and display in container on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie in react and javascript and recently start developed an app. I want to render the renderBoard array inside the boardContainer  div after i click  button .  Thx for any answers. This is the code for my component:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      size: [2, 2],
      renderBoard: false,
    }
    this.renderBoard = this.renderBoard.bind(this);
  }

  renderBoard() {
    var newWorld = [];
    var cellRow = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < this.state.size[0]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.size[1]; j++){
        cellRow.push(<Cell key={[i, j]} />);
      }
      newWorld.push(<div className="row" key={i}>{cellRow}</div>);
      cellRow = [];
    }
    return newWorld;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="headerButtons">
          <button className="submit" onClick= {this.renderBoard()}>Start</button>
        </div>
        Generation: 

        <div className="boardContainer">
          {this.renderBoard()}
        </div>
      </div>  
    );
  } 
}

class Cell extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cellContainer"></div>
    );
  }
}
export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state when you click the button instead of calling your render function. Do something like this:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      size: [2, 2],
      renderBoard: false,
    }
    this.renderBoard = this.renderBoard.bind(this);
  }

  renderBoard() {
    ....
  }

  showBoard => () => {
     this.setState({ renderBoard: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="headerButtons">
          <button className="submit" onClick={this.showBoard}>Start</button>
        </div>
        Generation: 
        <div className="boardContainer">
          {this.state.renderBoard ? this.renderBoard() : null}
        </div>
      </div>  
    );
  } 
}
```

or you could change your `renderBoard` function instead of using a ternary in your JSX like this:

```
renderBoard = () => {
  if (this.state.renderBoard) {
    ....
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I would also suggest renaming your state variable to be clearer. So maybe instead of `renderBoard` it would be `showBoard`. Then you'd use it like `if (this.state.showBoard)`. But that isn't required to make it work.